# Failed to connect to postgre database inside docker container

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose

**docker-compose.yaml**

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  web:
    env_file: .env
    build: .
    command: sh -c "alembic upgrade head && uvicorn main:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000"
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis
  db:
    image: postgres:11
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=${DB_USER}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${DB_PASS}
      - POSTGRES_DB=${DB_NAME}
  redis:
    image: redis:6-alpine

volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

**.env**

```
DB_USER='wplay'
DB_PASS='wplay'
DB_HOST=db
DB_NAME='wplay'
DB_PORT=5432
```

When I running docker container

```
web_1    | could not connect to server: Cannot assign requested address
web_1    |      Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
web_1    |      TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

I try to change .env `DB_HOST='localhost'` and add

```
ports:
  - '5432:5432'
```

to yaml `db` configuration, but nothing

upd

[image]

**logs**

```
db_1     | 
db_1     | PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization
db_1     | 
db_1     | 2023-01-04 12:44:55.386 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
db_1     | 2023-01-04 12:44:55.386 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
```

Connection to DB

**db.py**

```
import os
from decouple import config
import databases
import sqlalchemy


DEFAULT_DATABASE_URL = f"postgresql://{config('DB_USER')}:{config('DB_PASS')}" \
                       f"@{config('DB_HOST')}:5432/{config('DB_NAME')}"
DATABASE_URL = (os.getenv('DATABASE_URL', DEFAULT_DATABASE_URL))

database = databases.Database(DATABASE_URL)

metadata = sqlalchemy.MetaData()

engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(DATABASE_URL)
metadata.create_all(engine)
```

Comment: **localhost** from within the container is not the host's **localhost** by default. You should set `network_mode` to `host` in your *docker-compose.yaml* for container's **localhost** to point to host's **localhost**.

Comment: Your application code apparently either isn't seeing or isn't using the `$DB_HOST` variable.  Can you show where this environment variable is read and how the database connection is set up in your code?  The Compose file mostly looks fine (I'd remove the `command:` override and the `volumes:` for the `web` container) and you definitely do _not_ need host networking here.

Comment: @DavidMaze I've noticed that if  remove the `command` line from `web`, the coniner starts without errors. and I see that the variables from the `.env` are imported (see image ). But as soon as I try to interact with the database, e.g. running the `docker-compose migration exec web alembic upgrade head`, I get the same error.

Comment: It turns out that I connect to the database in the container `db`, but when I access the database, the system tries to connect to `localhost`.

Attached connection to DB logic file

Comment: That suggests to me that the `alembic update head` step is failing (does it need to run in an entrypoint wrapper script?).  Do you need to [include the database location in the `alembic.ini` file](https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/cookbook.html#run-multiple-alembic-environments-from-one-ini-file)?  (You may need to dynamically construct the file, and again an entrypoint wrapper script is a good match.)

Comment: Looked at my alembic.ini file. It seems to be the problem. The path is hardcoded like this
`sqlalchemy.url = postgresql://wplay:wplay@localhost/wplay`
Looks like all that's left is finding a way to pass environment variables into it, but that's not about docker anymore)

Answer (score -2):

You are spinning up two individual containers - a "web" and a "db" but trying to connect to the other by `localhost`.  `localhost` will only resolve to within it's own container.

**with Docker Run**

Use `--network="host"` in your `docker run` command, then `localhost` and `127.0.0.1` in your docker container will point to your docker host.

**With Docker Compose**

Each container can look up the hostname web or db and get back the appropriate container’s IP address. For example, `web`’s application code could connect to the URL `postgres://db:5432` and start using the Postgres database.

Within the `web` container, your connection string to db would look like `postgres://db:5432`

See [docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/network/host/) or [docker compose documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/)

Comment: I try to add    `environment:
      - DATABASE_URL=postgresql://${DB_USER}:${DB_PASS}@db:5432/${DB_NAME}` to `web` services. But the same result

Comment: it should be working if you have defined the ports for Db as well as provided the connection string as stated. Please re-read the linked Docker Compose documentation. 

ports:
      - "5432:5432"